# extract information from file based on conditions

Tags: shell, awk, sed

bPlease, I have a log file "log1.txt" that contains fields separated by the character "|" I want to retrieve rows according to specific requirements
and I have another configuration file "code.conf" or I put the values ​​found in the field 5.
here is the log file:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
abc|2|  11|   3| 1000|   13|scql| 0|   |   |   0|   0| plk| stv| 2| 0

trc|2|  20|   3| 1200|   30|tkgl|   0| pajd|jahd| 0| 0| klm|fdkl|1|0

klm|2|  0|   3| 1300|   19|mlpo|  0|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

klm|2|  20|   3| 1600|   11|mlpo|  19|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

And here is the configuration file "code.conf"

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
1000

1300

1200

1600
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Now I want to retrieve from the log file just lines corresponding to this conditions:

if  field 2 equal to "2" and field 4 equal to "3" and field 5 must contain one of the values ​​declared in the configuration file and (field 3 not equal to "0" or "20" or) or field 8 not equal to "0"

I tried this but doesn't works correctly :

```
  awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $2==2 && $4==3 && $5 in a && ($3!=0 || $3!=20)|| $8!=0 ' file
```

the output should be:

```
abc|2|  11|   3| 1000|   13|scql| 0|   |   |   0|   0| plk| stv| 2| 0

klm|2|  20|   3| 1600|   11|mlpo|  19|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

I think the error comes from the logic

thank you

Comment: How is 1600 in output when it is not in `code.conf`?

Comment: it's just a mistake the 1600 exist in code.conf i will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up `&&` and `||` in your awk command. Use this:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $2==2 && $4==3 && $5 in a && 
         (($3!=0 && $3!=20) || $8!=0)' code.conf file
abc|2|  11|   3| 1000|   13|scql| 0|   |   |   0|   0| plk| stv| 2| 0
klm|2|  20|   3| 1600|   11|mlpo|  19|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

Comment: but in case of the $3 equal to 0 or 20 and field $8  not equal to 0 it's a correct case

Comment: So you're getting your expected output aren't you?

Comment: no because if the field 3 $3  equal to 0 or 20 and the field $8 not equal to 0 this line must be present in output.

Comment: Provide better example in your question for this case since this output matches your expected output.

Comment: btw I tested again and this awk command does output a line where $3 is 20 and $8 is 19. Test it again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} ($2==2 && $4==3 && $5 in a &&$3 != 20) || $8 != 0)' code.conf test.txt
```

Comment: Unexplained blocks of code can be hard for inexperienced users to decipher, and don't help people to understand the solution. Could you briefly explain what this does, and how it fixes the problem?

Comment: Read the condition within awk and that's the difference.